# Reduce time spent sending emails from days to hours

Tags: email, smtp, exchange-server, sendgrid, amazon-ses

A client sends out monthly emails to about 1 million users which will grow with time. They currently send through an in-house exchange server.

Their current approach starts with first preparing all emails, recipients and attachments, then a script starts feeding the exchange server. Sending just a million mails generally takes days.

My role is to propose a better approach/solution that can get these emails sent and possibly delivered within hours. The choice of using 3rd party services like amazon ses and sendgrid exists but what will make the delivery time reduce as required.

Comment: Exchange Server's rate of accepting messages from the rendering server,  or the speed of the rendering server itself are factors to investigate, as is the size of the messages and the amount of bandwidth available.  I haven't worked on Exchange in a while, but it should have logs where you can correlate the times between when mails are queued, whether they experience transient issues, like timeouts, and when they are delivered.  Every message should have a unique ID in the log (created by the server).

Comment: thanks @Michael-sqlbot. I will ensure I troubleshoot on that end too.

Answer (score 2):

I'll start this with two disclaimers: 1) I am a SendGrid employee, 2) This question is right on the border of [questions StackOverflow doesn't like](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask).

---

That said, both SES or SendGrid will be able to process emails at a rate much faster than 1 million over several days.

Speaking for SendGrid, we accept all mail passed to us and queue it on our end, so if you're able to send a million emails at us in a second, we'll accept them and deal with queueing on our servers. So that answers the question of how fast you can get the mail away from you; leaving the question of how fast it will get to your users.
That's a harder question and depends on a number of factors, including if we're receiving negative feedback from email providers (Google, Yahoo, Comcast, etc.), and your typical send volume. All said, it could take anywhere from a few minutes to a few hours, but days is definitely unheard of.

As far as I know SES will do something of the same nature. SES enforces [client side send rates](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/ses/latest/DeveloperGuide/manage-sending-limits.html) (meaning you'll need to send them only `N` emails per period), but this can be upped greatly depending on your volume and trust. Again, as far as I know, SES should take anywhere in the neighborhood of minutes to hours to process and send 1m emails.

Comment: thanks nick. it's the way to go then. I apparently did not put my question well. However, you hit it when you talked about the "queuing" aspect. I want to believe the exchange server has a similar queuing feature which makes me wonder what they are currently doing wrong.